# Need to generate SubElement with xml content (not just text) using Python

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python and xml. I am using python to generate a xml file. This xml file will be generated daily based on some input configuration file. 
I Need some help in creating a subelement in my xml file. As it is not getting generated under the right parent element. Please current and desired outputs.

I have a wrapper python script and generator python script.
generator

### Wrapper Py script:

```
        with workflow.SubWFAction() as a:
            inp_list = [('catg','first')]
            a.app_path(TEST_FILE)
            a.configsec(inp_list)
            wf.insert_action(a)
```

---

Generator Py sript:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from xml.etree.ElementTree import SubElement
from xml.dom import minidom

class Workflow:
    def __init__(self, name, namespace=WF_NAMESPACE):
        self.xml = Element('workflow-app')
        self.action_counter = 0
    def insert_action(self, action):

class Action:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xml = Element('action')
        self._position = 0

class SubWFAction(Action):
    def __init__(self):
        Action.__init__(self)
        action_type = 'sub-workflow'
        self.xml.set('name', action_type)
        this_node = Element(action_type)
        self.xml.insert(self._position, this_node)
        self.sub_workflow = self.xml[self._position]

    def app_path(self, inner_text):
        node = SubElement(self.sub_workflow, 'app-path')
        cpnode = SubElement(self.sub_workflow, 'propagate-configuration')
        node.text = inner_text

    def configsec(self, inp_list):
        configuration = SubElement(self.sub_workflow, 'configuration')
        proptext = [self.property(prop[0], prop[1]) for prop in inp_list]
        return proptext

    def property(self, key, value):
        property = SubElement(self.xml,'property')
        name = SubElement(property,'name')
        name.text = key
        val = SubElement(property,'value')
        val.text = value
```

Current Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app name="wf_ntflx_genr" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="sub-workflow"/>
    <action name="sub-workflow">
        <sub-workflow>
            <app-path>
              /ntflx/tesfile.dat
            </app-path>
            <propagate-configuration/>
            <configuration/>
        </sub-workflow>
        <configuration/>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
        <property>
            <name>
                catg
            </name>
            <value>
                first
            </value>
        </property>
    </action>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app name="wf_ntflx_genr" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="sub-workflow"/>
    <action name="sub-workflow">
        <sub-workflow>
            <app-path>
              /ntflx/tesfile.dat
            </app-path>
            <propagate-configuration/>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>
                        catg
                    </name>
                    <value>
                        first
                    </value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </sub-workflow>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `<property>` to be under `<configuration>` so you need to supply the correct element to `SubElement`. You could do this several ways and I'm not sure which makes the most sense in your overall design. But one way is to track the current configuration and have `property` drop its data in there. I noted a potential bug in the code also...

```
def configsec(self, inp_list):
    # Changed: Remember the current configuration element so that
    # properties can be applied
    self.configuration = SubElement(self.sub_workflow, 'configuration')
    # TODO: this creates properties in the xml but since `property` 
    # returns `None` you return a list of `None`s here.
    proptext = [self.property(prop[0], prop[1]) for prop in inp_list]
    return proptext

def property(self, key, value):
    # changed: set the property element on the current configuration
    property = SubElement(self.configuration,'property')
    name = SubElement(property,'name')
    name.text = key
    val = SubElement(property,'value')
    val.text = value
```

Comment: Thanks tdelaney. This change resolved my problem. May I know what is the bug you noticed.

Comment: You created the `<property>` element with `property = SubElement(self.xml,'property')` but `self.xml` doesn't reference the `<configuration>` element. I'll add a couple of comments for the changes.